# Using FOR command to list all the files in directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I had 4 files with name like `cp1_26_09_2015.txt`, `cp1_22_02_2015`, `cp1_28_09_2015` and etc in the same date format in 4 different subfolders of the `D:\drive`.

I wanted to search for a file one by one when I am using the `FOR` command to list all the files in directory and subdirectory.

Then it lists out 4 names of this text file in 4 different folders but I wanted the path to be extracted one by one so that I could perform operations one by one on each file. So till now I have constructed this:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
setlocal
SET /A MAXJ=1
SET /A J=1

set _T1=%date:.=%
set  _year=%_T1:~-4,4%  
set  _month=%_T1:~-10,2%  
set  _day=%_T1:~-7,2%   
cp1_26_09_2015.txt
set _prefix=cp1
PAUSE
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%i IN (`DIR /S /B D:\cp1*.txt`)  DO ( IF NOT "%%~nxi"==**%_prefix%_%_year%_%_month%_%_day%.txt** (
    SET XCOUNT_!J!=%%~i
    SET MAXJ=!J!
    SET /A J+=1
)
)
SET XCOUNT

SET /A J-=1
@echo COUNT OF FILES IS : %J%
PAUSE
```

Now the problem here is when I try to remove today's date file in the search with file name as `cp1_28_09_2015.txt` where date variables in the extension name are provided in `%_month%`, `%_year%` and `%_day%` this is not working, reporting a syntax error.

Comment: so what's the problem? instead of echo, do your operation.

Comment: i wanted to get path one by one

Comment: right now i am getting

Comment: D:\A1\CP1_26_09_2015  D:\A2\CP1_26_09_2015   D:\A3\CP1_26_09_2015   D:\A4\CP1_26_09_2015

Comment: yes, and you ARE getting the paths one by one.

Comment: I am interested in extracting a single path one at a time where as %i returning all 4 files path on screen

Comment: no, it's not. it's PRINTING THEM to screen via the echo, but it's printing each path individually. that's the whole point of `for`...

Comment: Thank you but how can i use %i as a parameter to be passed in next operation to get only single path of single file name

Comment: `for(...) do yourcommand %i`

Comment: There is a space missing between `in` and `(`...

Comment: @MarcB  i had edited the question there is a small syntax problem

Answer (score 1):

Make a BAT file and try like this :

```
    @echo off
    FOR /R "D:\" %%i in (*_26_09_2015.txt) do call:test %%i
    echo Done !
    exit/b

    :test
    echo working on : %1
    echo Do what you want with %1
```

**NEW EDIT :**

Try this :

```
@echo off

set  "_year=%date:~6,4%"  
set  "_month=%date:~3,2%"  
set  "_day=%date:~0,2%"   
set "_prefix=cp1"

For /f "tokens=*" %%i IN ('DIR /S /B cp1*.txt')  do (
  If /i not "%%~nxi"=="%_prefix%_%_day%_%_month%_%_year%.txt" (
    call:next "%%~nxi")
)

exit/b

:next
echo make something with : %1
echo who don't have the today date
pause
```

Comment: please remove cp1_26_09_2015.txt from the code and ignore ** from the code snippet where i had edited this question and provided the code

Comment: @SachaDee still the output is not as expected

Answer (score 0):

In case you want it to search for a single file, then make a file listtest.cmd like this:

```
@echo off
set testparams=%1
echo Listing files with name %1.
echo ====
FOR /R "D:\" %%i in (*_26_09_2015.txt) do call :filetest %%i
echo ====
echo Done.
exit /b
:filetest
if %1 == %testparams% echo %1
```

Then run it from the command line using the following syntax;

```
listtest <filesearch>
```

where filesearch is the file you want it to find.

If you don't know how to make CMD files and running them from command line, please comment this answer.